# Erro error `while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0:...` ao executar PacketTracer 7 no fedora 25

Tags: linux

ao tentar executar o packet tracer no fedora 25 ele apresenta o seguinte erro.

```
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema Resolvido Só para se caso alguém instale usando o fedora 25 e dê o mesma problema segue os passos.

Inicialmente Procurei a uma pasta que tem a lib usando o seguinte comando.

```
locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

A unica pasta que possuia era a /usr/local/lib/warsaw/libcrypto.so.1.0.0

copiei a lib para 2 pastas só para garantir a lib na pasta de instalação do packettracer utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/warsaw/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /opt/pt/lib
```

e também para a pasta /usr/lib

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/warsaw/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib
```

Depois percebi, que cada vez que executa o packetTracer ele dava um problema de permisão em um daemon do linux, utilizando a ferramenta "log" do fedora que vem instalado nativamente, só procurar nos aplicativos.

O comando de permissão

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/warsaw
```